# QT Creator IDE unexpectedly close immediately when I press on "Open Project" Button

Tags: qt-creator, centos6

I installed Qt Creator 3.1.2 on my cent os system.

It is Based on Qt 5.3.1 (GCC 4.6.1, 32 bit)

every thing works fine except "open project"

When I run the program via terminal I see this warning message at first:

> (:10415): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempt to load unknown IM context
>   type 'gtk-im-context-none'

meanwhile the program starts and I can create new project or etc.

**BUT when I press on "Open Project" button the IDE is closed unexpectedly.**

I checked the terminal and I saw system shows me this error message:

> /opt/Qt5.3.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator: symbol lookup error:
>   /opt/Qt5.3.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk2.so:
>   undefined symbol: gtk_dialog_get_widget_for_response

what is your solution to repair this problem?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be, your CentOS is too old, it has too old version of GTK *compared to the machine where the Qt Creator was built*.

One thing you *could* try, is simply remove the GTK plugin `/opt/Qt5.3.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk2.so`. With luck, then Qt Creator will just not have have GTK/Gnome desktop integration, but will otherwise work.

Otherwise, if you can't upgrade your OS, and above "solution" is not satisfactory, you need to build Qt and/or Qt Creator yourself, so it will be correctly configured for your system. This [bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-30610) (since fixed) seems to indicate, that issue is with the Qt libraries (Creator binary bundles the Qt libs it was built against), so you I think you have to start by building Qt yourself.

Comment: @Mehrdad201 Well, instead of removing, I'd rename, so it's possible to restore it. At that location, you probably need to be root, so 1. open terminal window, 2. become root (with `su` or `sudo`, google for how to do it in CentOs). 3. `cd /opt/Qt5.3.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/plugins/platformthemes`. 4. `mv libqgtk2.so libqgtk2.so.backup`.

Comment: Dear hyde, I renamed mv libqgtk2.so to mv libqgtk2.so.backup but the problem still exists. :(

Comment: @Mehrdad201 You mean, you still get `/opt/Qt5.3.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk2.so: undefined symbol: ...`, even though the file is not there? Are you sure? Try `ls -l /opt/Qt5.3.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/plugins/platformthemes/libqgtk2.so` to verify it is really gone.

Comment: Yes, I renamed the file and in LS , there was no libqgtk2.so. the result was libqgtk2.so.backup -- but I had the problem in open project and I don't what can I do.

Comment: Dear hyde, I deleted libqgtk2.so and problem is gone. I think rename file doesn't solve the problem because in warning message I saw the program has a connection between renamed file. so I remove your mentioned file and problem is gone.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Interesting that rename was not enough. But good that you got it to work!